# Mount changes directory time to 1970

Tags: mount, date, timestamps, busybox

We are developing an embedded Linux system using BusyBox v1.19.4. The system is working fine except for a strange mount issue with time and date.

When we create a directory it has the correct time and date:

```
\$ ls -l
drwxrwxrwx    2 root     root            40 Jul 21 16:16 media_2e040
\$
```

However, once we mount a device, the time and date changes:

```
\$ mount /dev/sdb1 media_2e040
\$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x    9 root     root         16384 Jan  1  1970 media_2e040
\$
```

Not knowing much about mounting, I can run `touch` on the directory, and the time/date updates to the correct time.

Is there a reason for this operation of mount?

Should we be running `touch` to keep the time and date?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your drive `/dev/sdb1` is mounted in `media_2e040` directory now so all the properties of `media_2e049` are `sdb1` properties. if you change them with `touch` you have changed `sdb1` properties.

Comment: Is there a way of preserving the time/date of the directory?

Comment: after unmounting it with `umount media_2e040` the original properties of this folder will come back. the fact is think of `media_2e040` as `/dev/sdb1` partition after mounting and before unmounting.